# Get total number of review of permanently closed place in google map without API

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am learning python as well as web scrapping and I want to get number of review from google map of a permanently closed restaurant but I cannot do that, would you please help? Thank you

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.google.com/maps?q=asia+halal+restaurant+aichi+japan+open+date&safe=strict&rlz=1C1GCEA_enID892ID892&sxsrf=ALeKk01NqaBLM8bXeVVS6M6tv9kAy0G6qQ:1616997971678&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgjELADECc6BQghEKABOgQIIRAVOgcIIRAKEKABUIUIWKojYOckaABwAHgAgAHHAogB7RGSAQcxLjUuNC4ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBAcABAQ&uact=5&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbhef-7NTvAhWa93MBHaFHCzYQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw'

import requests
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
ps = soup.find_all(string = 'クチコミ')
ps
```

I also tried to use find 'class' and 'span aria-label' based on developer tool of chrome below but still cannot do that

[browser picture for html class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7sef.jpg)

```
#ps = soup.find_all(class_='h0ySl-wcwwM-E70qVe-list')
#ps = soup.find_all('span aria-label')
#total_rev = ps.get_text()
#total_rev
```

Here is the code that I tried using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/Download/SW/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%90%E3%82%B7+%E3%82%B9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84/@35.0903185,136.8551766,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x600378381c4bb1f7:0x8e9d356b9ded5bcc!8m2!3d35.0903185!4d136.8573653'
driver.get(url)
```

I have tried to get number of review using this code in "still operating" restaurant, but when it comes to permanently closed one I cannot get the number of review

```
span_review = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "section-star")]'))).click()


#Find the total number of reviews
total_number_of_reviews = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pane"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]').text.split(" ")[0]
total_number_of_reviews = int(total_number_of_reviews.replace(',','')) if ',' in total_number_of_reviews else int(total_number_of_reviews)#Find scroll layout


total_reviews = driver.find_element_by_class_name("h0ySl-wcwwM-E70qVe-list")
total_reviews #= driver.get('aria-label')
total_reviews = total_reviews.get_text('aria-label')
total_reviews
total_reviews
total_number_of_reviews = total_reviews.text[0:]

total_number_of_reviews
```

Hopefully I can learn

Thanks!

Comment: Google Maps uses JavaScript but `requests`, `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. it would need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. But Google may also try to block all bots/scripts/spamers/hackers which try to use Google Maps directly. Google Maps are created for human (which watch ads and Google earn money) and Google created API for scripts/bots/etc.

Comment: Thank you @furas for your suggestion, I tried to use selenium (edited the post) but still cannot get number of review
I mean, I can get number of review in  "still operating" restaurant, but when it comes to permanently closed one I cannot get the number of review
Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: I can't find your xpath in HTML. You use `'//button[contains(text(), "section-star")]')` but in HTML I see only `<li class="section-star">`. Maybe it sends different HTML in your country. It may also send differnt HTML for `still operating` and for `permanently closed` - permanently closed may no need buttons to change stars.

Comment: `aria-label` is not text but `attribute` and you have to use `.get_attribute('aria-label')`

Comment: I misunderstood about aria-label. Also I learned how to use html in a good way from your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: all inside tag `<..>` is attribute (except tag name) - `class`, `id`, `name`, `aria-label`, `src`, `href`, and page may also use own/non-standard attributes like `data-src` and you can get them also with `.get_attribute()`. `text` is between opening tag `< .. >` and closing `</...>` - ie. `<a>text</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find your `xpath` in HTML. There is no `<button>` with text `section-star` but `<li class="section-star">`.

And `aria-label` is not text but `attribute` and you have to use `.get_attribute('aria-label')`

But I found other xpath `//button[jsaction="pane.rating.moreReviews"]` and it works for me for `permanent closed` and `still operating`

---

Tested on Firefox and Chrome, Linux.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/Download/SW/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()

all_urls = [
    # permanent closed
    'https://www.google.com/maps/place/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%90%E3%82%B7+%E3%82%B9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84/@35.0903185,136.8551766,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x600378381c4bb1f7:0x8e9d356b9ded5bcc!8m2!3d35.0903185!4d136.8573653',
    # still operating
    'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Seaside+Restaurant+Higashiyama+Garden+-+Port+Bldg./@35.0841323,136.8474088,14z/data=!3m1!5s0x6003790a61e056e7:0x7f307de064680a96!4m9!1m2!2m1!1srestaurants!3m5!1s0x600379a07cd9fcc7:0x89f84cc9f0422e30!8m2!3d35.0895485!4d136.8809243!15sCgtyZXN0YXVyYW50c1oNIgtyZXN0YXVyYW50c5IBCnJlc3RhdXJhbnQ',
]

for url in all_urls:
    driver.get(url)
    total_reviews = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@jsaction="pane.rating.moreReviews"]')))
    total_reviews = total_reviews.get_attribute('aria-label')
    print(total_reviews)
```